# How to get a range of items from vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, slice

I need to get a range of elements from `std::vector`. Similar to the python slice operator:

```py
range = vector[0:n]
```

The obvious way is to iterate through the required elements. Is there any other better way?

Comment: what's wrong with the obvious way?

Comment: it's too long and also it's always good for me to get a new way for obvious things

Comment: C++ is a very verbose language (get used to it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of vector's constructors is:

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

So you need only create a new vector passing the required iterators.

Answer (score 5):

`vector<T>` has a constructor that takes two iterators that identify a range.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> range( &v[0], &v[0]+n );
```

Note that this would work even if `v` is a regular array and not a `vector` because a pointer to an element in an array behaves like an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ land, instead of using ranges, iterators are used. An iterator is an index into the container that points to a certain element. So to get an iterator to the beginning, you use `vec.begin()`, and to get an iterator to `n` you use `vec.begin() + n`. If you want to iterate over this, you can simply do

```
for (atd::vector<Foo>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.begin() + n; ++it)
```

If you want to make a new vector, you can use the constructor that Luchian mentions like so:

```
std::vector<Foo> vec2(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + n)
```

Comment: By the way, there's an attempt to bring ranges to C++-land in [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).